# Removing a specific line from a file

Tags: text-processing

Somewhere in the middle of my CSV file is this line:

```
Products below this line are out of stockNumber, month, year, reference, store
```

Note:Number, month, year, reference and store are the CSV fields.

How do I delete this line from the file using a command line command?

Note the CSV is like this

```
Number, month, year, reference, store
1,1,2014,13322,main
2,2,2014,13322,main
3,3,2011,1322,main
4,4,2012,3322,main
5,4,2013,122,secondary
Products below this line are out of stockNumber, month, year, reference, store
12,411,2010,122,Albany
25,41,2009,122,Dallas
35,24,2008,122,New
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way is using `grep -v` command:

```sh
grep -v "Products below" your_file.csv > new_file.csv
```

Answer (score 11):

With your input data, you can try:

```
$ sed '/^Products/d' file 
Number, month, year, reference, store
1,1,2014,13322,main
2,2,2014,13322,main
3,3,2011,1322,main
4,4,2012,3322,main
5,4,2013,122,secondary
12,411,2010,122,Albany
25,41,2009,122,Dallas
35,24,2008,122,New
```

Using `sed -i.bak` to edit the file inplace and create a backup file:

```
sed -i.bak '/^Products/d' file
```

Comment: with certain versions of `sed` you don't need to do `-i.bak` just `-i` will do (but of course w/o backup file)

Comment: @user13107 in some versions you have to say `-i''` for that though

Comment: @SztupY: In `-i''` the shell should strip the `''` and leave you with `-i` alone. At least if it is a standard bourne-like shell.

Comment: @MvG: missed the space between `-i` and `''`

Answer (score 6):

If we can safely assume that you want to delete all lines that start with `Products` (including the space after the 1st word), these will all work:

- awk

  ```
  awk '$1!="Products" file > newfile
  ```
- perl

  ```
  perl -ne 'print unless /^Products/' file > newfile
  ```

  or

  ```
  perl -ane 'print if $F[0]!="Products"' file > newfile
  ```

  or, to edit the file in place

  ```
  perl -i -ne 'print unless /^Products/; ' file
  perl -i -ane 'print if $F[0]!="Products"' file
  ```
- grep (this is just a shorter version of [svq's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141208/22222))

  ```
   grep -v ^Products file > newfile
  ```
- bash (just for the fun of it)

  ```
  while read line; do [[ $line =~ ^Products ]] || echo $line; done <  file > newfile
  ```

Answer (score 5):

in-place with `ed` (on the `bash` prompt)

```
ed -s file <<<$'/Products below/d\nw'
```

Or as [don crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) [recommends:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141206/removing-a-specific-line-from-a-file/141223?noredirect=1#comment323102_141223)

```
ed -s file <<<$'/Products below/d\nw\nq'
```

Comment: `ed` answers always deserve a +1

Comment: seconding @evilsoup ; though if you want to go by the book you should add the `q`uit subcommand too: `$'/Products below/d\nw\nq'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` to search pattern to delete each line what contain this pattern

```
sed -i '/Products below this line are out of stockNumber, month, year, reference, store/d' file
```

Answer (score 3):

perl oneliner:

```
perl -ne 'print unless (m/Products below/') FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another example of using `sed`:

```
sed '/^Products below this line are out of stockNumber, month, year, reference, store$/d' originalDocument > newDocument
```